# using datetime.time() in while loop

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Working with pandas dataframes, I have a while condition like this:

```
while (i+1<len(df.index)) and (pr<pb and pr>sl) and (df['Buy/Sell'].iloc[i+1]!=2):
```

I want to add another condition that df['Time'] should be earlier than 15:25.
I have obtained df['Time'] in the following manner:

```
df['Time'] = df.apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x['Time'],'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), axis=1)
```

When I add the following condition to while loop:

```
and (df['Time']<datetime.time(15,25,0)):
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp
```

EDIT: I am doing something with the values in other columns in the dataframe according to the while loop. I need to stop if the the time in the 'time' column reaches 15:27, or if the other conditions mentioned don't hold anymore. My code is working perfectly fine if I don't need the 15:27 condition.

Note: `df.dtypes` returns the following:

`Time              datetime64[ns]`

EDIT: Doing

```
`while (i+1<len(df.index)) and (pr<pb and pr>sl) and df['Buy/Sell'].iloc[i+1]!=2) and df['time'].dt.time<datetime.time(15,27,0))`
```

I get this error now:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Is this a typo `and  (df['time']<datetime.time(15,25,0))`? shouldn't it be `df['Time`]`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Don't you want to compare the time component rather than a datetime? `and (df['Time'].dt.time < datetime.time(15,25,0))`?

Comment: I did what you suggested.
Getting this error.
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I need to extract only the time component from df['Time'] and check if the time is earlier than 15:27

Comment: Can you post what you're trying to achieve here, you probably don't need to compare row-wise you can just do `df.loc[df['Time'].dt.time < datetime.time(15,25,0)]` # do something

Comment: You're comparing a scalar value against an array like object which is why the error is raised, if you want to iterate row-wise then you need to select a specific row e.g. `and df.loc[i, 'Time'].time < datetime.time(15,25,0)` where `i` is your iterating index value

Comment: Thank you. A parenthesis is missing, though.
df.loc[i, 'time'].time() < datetime.time(15,25,0) works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because of this line:

```
and (df['Time']<datetime.time(15,25,0)):
```

Firstly you want to compare the `time` component rather than a datetime with a time object, secondly you can't compare a scalar with an array like object so you want to do the following:

```
df.loc[i, 'time'].time() < datetime.time(15,25,0)
```

This access a single row value and then the `time` attribute.

Ideally you don't want to iterate row-wise if possible rewrite your filtering and use the `dt` accessor to get the `time` attribute for your entire series:

`df.loc[df['Time'].dt.time < datetime.time(15,25,0)]` will filter your entire df